# How to align the logo and a text in the same row using Bootstrap 3.0?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstarp 3.0, I want to align horizontally a logo and a text. The code would be like:

```
<div>        
  <div >
<img class="" alt="" src="/img/my_logo.gif"></img>
  </div>
  <div >
     <p>My text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can use the grid system of bootstrap, but I do not want to define widths. What I want, is that the first column with is the with of the bitmap, and the with of second column (the text), is the remaining space.

Answer (score 2):

Use Bootstrap's `list-inline`..

```
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/150x50"></li>
    <li><p>My text</p></li>
  </ul>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/126441

Comment: It works, but how can I vertically align by top? Now, if the text has many lines, the logo is aligned at the center of the vertical.

Answer (score 1):

your div have no bootstrap class

I suggest you to look the "[row](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)" boostrap-classes used for align the div

for example

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">img</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was my first attempt, but it divides the row in two similar widths. What I need is to put the text near to the logo, and the text width must be the remaining space.